# VB6: validating date with a certain format

Tags: validation, date, vb6, format

I have built a form using Visual Basic 6. Everything goes great, the form inserts the data in my database and no problems here at all.

Now I need to validate the date field, I need the dates entered to have this format: dd/mm/yyyy

I'm doing:

```
Private Sub txtMyText_Validate(Index As Integer, Cancel As Boolean)
If IsDate(Format$(txtMyText(9).Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")) Or txtMyText(9).Text = "" Then
txtMyText(9).SetFocus
Else
txtMyText(9).SetFocus
MsgBox "Please enter a valid date with this format: dd/mm/yyyy."
End If
End Sub
```

But this code is not working.  When I enter a date with this format dd/mm/yy the flow follows to the inserting function and I get an error there cause it is not a dd/mm/yyyy.

Can you please help me  to fix this code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be a good idea too use a specific date control, e.g. DateTimePicker, for date input instead of using text control.  DateTimePicker has a Value property that is of type Date.

Comment: The code you failed is trying to convert the entered date to "dd/mm/yyyy" format and then checking if it's a date. The best method is to use a date picker or allow freeform and checking with `IsDate()` and `CDate()`.

Comment: I would echo the above two comments - how do you know what format the user entered the date in? The only way to be sure is to use something like a datetimepicker control

Comment: if the user enters "02/05/2013" then you can never know wether he meant the 2nd of may, or the 5th of february .. also be sure to check the regional settings of the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your insert into database line for the date field:

```
Format(txtMyText(9).Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

That will solve dates entered as dd/mm/yy or yyyy/mm/dd

And to prevent from entering integers or strings instead of dates:

```
Private Sub txtMyText_Validate(Index As Integer, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not IsDate(txtMyText(9).Text) Then
    MsgBox "Enter a valid date with this format: dd/mm/yyyy"
    Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As with anything that requires a specific format, it is always best to rely on software than to rely on a person. This example might convert unambiguous dates to `"dd/mm/yyyy"` but it won't always know if `"01/10/2013"` is January 10th or October 1st. Don't allow the user to make this kind of mistake. Use a `DateTimePicker` control, as suggested in another answer.