# Visual basic 6: check if a date is in the future

Tags: forms, validation, date, vb6, future

I have a form made with VB6 and I need to check the date field for future dates.

If the date entered is in the future an error message should show and if it is not, the validation should finish.

I’ve done:

```
Private Sub txtDate_Validate(Index As Integer, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not IsDate(txtDate(9).Text) Then 'first I check if the data entered is a date
'error message saying the field needs a valid date
  Cancel = True
        Else
      If (txtDate(9).Text > Date) Then 'now I check if the date entered is bigger than today’s date 
                'error message saying the date is in the future 
                Cancel = True
            Else
               Exit Sub
            End If
       End If 
End If
End Sub
```

This code does not work because

```
txtDate(9).Text > Date
```

is always true

Even if I do:

```
Format(txtDate(9).Text, "dd/mm/yyyy") > Date
```

is always true too

What can I do to fix this? How can I know if the date entered is in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: Convert txtDate(9).text To a Date. Programming rule #356, do not do date arithmetic with strings.

Comment: Cdate, I've found it! Please make your comment a post so I can accept it. Thanks a lot, a VB6 learner here !

Comment: Oddly enough, you were [told this last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558797/vb6-validating-date-with-a-certain-format#comment20315498_14558797) :)

Comment: Yes, I told myself answering my own question! :D The difference here is that I totally believed that txtDate(9).Text was already a date so I thought it as a programming problem not a type conversion one  .. the learning curve is tricky, now I know  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CDate to convert the content of the textbox to a Date.

Can't stress this enough if it's got quotes round it, it's a string.

Comment: The `.Text` kinds' implies that it's text though :p